Enable OpenSSL FIPS mode for Boost C++
Question
Looking thru these various OpenSSL 3.0 docs

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34791/openssl-vs-fips-enabled-openssl
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/README-FIPS.md
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/fips_module.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2

I've managed to piece together a solution to enable FIPS mode in OpenSSL with the following goal in mind:

The emphasis is on the fact that once FIPS mode is enabled in OpenSSL,
all cryptographic operations performed through OpenSSL, including
those used by C++ Boost.Asio for SSL/TLS connections, will utilize
FIPS-approved algorithms, ensuring compliance with FIPS standards
throughout the Boost C++ application.

Is this a valid function enableFIPS() to enable OpenSSL FIPS mode for Boost C++?
Example
main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <openssl/provider.h>

bool PrintErrorSSL(const std::string& err)
{
   std::cerr << err << std::endl;
   unsigned long err_code;
   while ((err_code = ERR_get_error()) != 0)
   {
      char err_msg[256];
      ERR_error_string_n(err_code, err_msg, sizeof(err_msg));
      std::cerr << "OpenSSL error: " << err_msg << std::endl;
   }
   // FIPS mode not enabled.
   return false;
}

bool enableFIPS()
{
   std::string ConfigPath;
   std::string TestPath = "C:/Projects/sys-openssl-fips/Test/";
   
#ifdef _WIN32
    ConfigPath = TestPath + "openssl-fips.cnf";
#else
    ConfigPath = TestPath + "openssl-fips-linux.cnf";
#endif

   if (!OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path(nullptr, TestPath.c_str()))
   {
      return PrintErrorSSL("OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path() Failed");
   }

   if (!OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config(nullptr, ConfigPath.c_str()))
   {
      return PrintErrorSSL("OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config() Failed");
   }

   if (!OSSL_PROVIDER_available(nullptr, "fips") || !OSSL_PROVIDER_available(nullptr, "base"))
   {
      return PrintErrorSSL("OSSL_PROVIDER_available() Failed");
   }

   if (!EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled(nullptr))
   {
      return PrintErrorSSL("EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled() Failed");
   }

   // FIPS mode enabled.
   return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if (enableFIPS())
   {
      using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
      boost::asio::io_context io_context;
      boost::asio::ssl::context ssl_context(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12);
      boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket(io_context, ssl_context);
      tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
      auto endpoints = resolver.resolve("www.google.com", "443");
      boost::asio::connect(socket.lowest_layer(), endpoints);
      socket.handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client);
      std::string request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
      boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(request));
      boost::asio::streambuf response;
      boost::system::error_code ec;
      boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n", ec);
      std::istream response_stream(&response);
      std::string http_status;
      std::getline(response_stream, http_status);
      if (http_status.find("200 OK") != std::string::npos)
         return 0;
   }

   return 1;
}

openssl-fips.cnf
config_diagnostics = 1
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[fips_sect]
activate = 1
conditional-errors = 1
security-checks = 1
module-mac = D9:AB:CC:37:8A:4C:06:BF:E9:E3:A8:F7:B9:B5:02:48:58:71:76:EB:5E:71:8A:0F:87:AA:52:46:7D:60:B0:EB

[openssl_init]
providers = provider_sect
alg_section = algorithm_sect

[provider_sect]
fips = fips_sect
base = base_sect

[base_sect]
activate = 1

[algorithm_sect]
default_properties = fips=yes

Output (Windows)
OpenSSL FIPS mode: OFF
Projects will utilize non FIPS-approved algorithms provided by these openssl static libraries

libssl - Implements the Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol.
libcrypto - Implements cryptographic algorithms.

OpenSSL FIPS mode: ON
Projects will utilize FIPS-approved algorithms provided by these openssl shared libraries

fips.so (on Linux)
fips.dll (on Windows)

Using Process Explorer, the fips.dll is loaded:


It looks close.
I'd say you have to be careful with using the particular constructor for asio::ssl::context. It looks like enableFIPS mostly sets defaults, so perhaps to be safe you could also manually instantiate an SSL_CTX* and construct asio::ssl::context from it using https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/context/overload2.html
Beyond that, I'd always vouch for compliance tests. Of course you could start with some in-house unit/integration tests that check that improper configurations are actively rejected.

Oh, by the way, I get this is just a sample program, but manually parsing HTTP like this is a recipe for security issues that no amount of FIPS certification can make up for. Always use existing tech like Boost Beast or libcurl.

Thanks, I've spent several days just getting to this minimal repro. In relation to contexts, I initially tried using OSSL_LIB_CTX_new() but that required maintenance to use and free it later, then I realized an OpenSSL default context exists, so I went with that. But, I'll look into your suggestion about manually instantiating an SSL_CTX* too.  :)

Yes. And the constructor I linked takes ownership, so you don't even require management/freeing later.
